# How can I make the output return False if a character in the string appears three times in a row?

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I created this code that takes in a list and returns True or False depending on whether they meet these criterias or not. Here is my code

```
def passwordlength(password: str):
    upper = digit = special = False
    for char in password:
        if char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" :
            upper = True
        elif char in "1234567890":
            digit = True
        elif char in "$#@%!":
            special = True
    return upper and digit and special

def passwordOK(password: str):
    if passwordlength(password):
        if not (6 < len(password) < 12):
            return False
        else:
            return True
    return False
```

Now I want to add a new twist, which is that if any letter, number, character in the list appears 3 times in a row, the result will return False.. here is my attempt at it...

```
    def passwordlength(password: str):
    upper = digit = special = False
    for char in password:
        if char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" :
            upper = True
        elif char in "1234567890":
            digit = True
        elif char in "$#@%!":
            special = True
    return upper and digit and special

def passwordOK(password: str):
    if passwordlength(password):
        if not (6 < len(password) < 12):
            return False
        for char in password:
            if password.count(char) > 3:
                return False
        return True
    return False
```

However, this clearly doesn't work at all.. what am I doing wrong here??
what should my code be in order for my output to be correct??

Comment: Think about how you'd do this on paper. You'd keep track of the previous character you've read; if the next character is the same, then you would set a mental "flag" indicating that if the next character is also the same, then there's 3 of the same character in a row. That kind of thinking should be pretty easy to translate to code. If you ever get stuck on things like this in the future, just realize that code is a way to transfer logical and structured thinking into a computer. So, if you can reason your way through a task, you can put it into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `return false` when a character, number appears 3 times in the string, clearly you should change your if condition like this:

```py
[...]
for char in password:
    if password.count(char) == 3:
        return False
[...]
```

If you meant at least 3 times appearance:

```py
[...]
for char in password:
    if password.count(char) >= 3:
        return False
[...]
```

However `password.count(char)` will loop over the whole `password` for each `char`, so why don't we loop once, and get the result:

```py
[...]
from collections import defaultdict
defdict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for char in password:
    defdict[char] += 1
    if defdict[char] >= 3:
        return false
[...]
```

### Update:

according to your comment:

> I mean like 3 times in a row btw, like if its AAA, BBB, CCC then it should return false.. if it's ABANA.. then it doesn't matter

Define a function like this:

```py
def has_3consecutive_char(password: str) -> bool:
    from collections import defaultdict
    defdict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    prev_char = ""
    for char in password:
        if prev_char == char:
            defdict[char] += 1
            if defdict[char] >= 2:
                return True
        else:
            defdict[char] = 0
        prev_char = char
    return False
```

Then use it in your `passwordOK` function:

```py
def passwordOK(password: str):
    if passwordlength(password):
        if not (6 < len(password) < 12):
            return False
        if has_3consecutive_char(password):
                return False
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: I mean like 3 times in a row btw, like if its AAA, BBB, CCC then it should return false.. if it's ABANA.. then it doesn't matter

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JoshuaBradley. I have updated my answer according to your comment.

Comment: I've updated it again @JoshuaBradley Please check it. This will work 100%

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` from `itertools`. With this version, you set the number of characters in a row.

```
from itertools import groupby

def passwordinarow(password: str, n: int=3):
    """Return True if password contains 'n' characters in a row else False."""
    return any([len(list(g)) >= n for c, g in groupby(password)])
```

Test:

```
>>> passwordinarow('AAABC123$')
True

>>> passwordinarow('ABC123$')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to approach this.

Personally I might do something like:

```
def has_repeated_chars(password: str, n_repetitions: int=3) -> bool:
    ngrams = zip(*(password[i] for i in range(n_repetitions)))
    return min(len(set(trigram)) for trigram in ngrams) == 1
```

Generally the logic is to create an iterable of ngrams of length 3, create a set for each ngram and if the set is of length 1 then we know the same character has been repeated 3 times.

Comment: While this works, I think it'd be really hard for a beginner to understand what's going on when everything is uncommented and condensed down to two crammed line like this. I think breaking it up into individual lines, and having comments explaining everything, would be necessary for anyone but a Python expert to understand what's going on here.